# Angular 2 Environment Variables - Setting basic auth password

Tags: javascript, angular, heroku

I wrote a very simple service using sails.js. It uses Basic Authentication for access to its services.

I also have a separate front end written in Angular, using the @angular/cli.

I have two sets of environment variables to set for prod and dev. For example:

```
// dev
ADMIN=admin
ADMIN_PASS=mypassword123
API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:1337/endpoint
```

This would obviously be different for prod. My issue is that I am deploying this using Heroku. You can easily set the env vars in heroku, but I don't know how to access them. I know you can set things in `src/environments` but this would then put my variables in code control.

I have also tried `process.env` but I learned this is a node.js thing not and angular thing.

**How do I access system environment variables from angular2?**

example of how I'd us it:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class HeroService {
   private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // <- this should be grabbed from environment
   private adminUser = 'admin'; // this line too...
   private adminPass = 'myPassword'; // same with this line... 
   constructor (private http: Http) {}
   getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> { ...}
 }
```

Comment: So do you want to acces these variables during deployment or while running the app?

Comment: My thought was both? like, I'll have a `service/something.js that` will make make calls to some api endpoint using the values above.

Comment: Why are you protecting your API when you want to show the authentication data public to each client?

Comment: I don't. This is communication from one app to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Programing Point of View

Use `process.env` then server side(nodejs) can put them into a structure. Since you are using `sails.js`, setup a `post` route or an api call that will send this structure in json format.

Front end(browser) app can make a http.post call to pick it up at run time.

This way the set of parameters are not bundled/hardcoded in your front end app code base.

#### Security Point of View

If password credential is required for 3rd party service, such call is better handled from the server side like following:

(browser) -- api call --> (your server) -- api call --> (3rd-party)

This way credential to 3rd party is not exposed. And api call to your server should be protected by some authentication mechanism.

Comment: How do I access those in angular?

Comment: Angular is running in the browser (clientside) you absolutely don't want to make this variables visible to the client side (assuming they sould be kept secret)

Comment: Won't that expose my vars to whoever makes a post call?

Comment: @jeff  I was trying to solve the issue from pure programing pov. Updated answer with security concern.

Comment: @Jeff Does this answer your questions?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it.